# Delay asana task creation notification in slack

Tags: asana, slack

I have integrated Slack with Asana. Notifications are sent to slack as soon as the task is created.

But there is no delay. As soon as I create a task, the notification is sent. Problem is that sometimes, I have not created the task fully, but the notification is sent with half the details.
Once I complete creating the task, another notification is sent.

Basically, Slack is flooded with Asana tasks some of which are incomplete and meaningless.

I have checked the edit configuration option online.
https://[teamname].slack.com/services/[slack-asana-integration-id].
It has features only to select the slack channel, projects in Asana etc. Nothing to choose the frequency of scanning the Asana.

How to control the frequency of task creation notification ?

Answer (score 1):

Currently it isn't possible. Slack are using a new feature of our (Asana's) API that feeds them instant updates. We're going to look into adding support to our API to make this experience better, and I've also passed this along to Slack to see if they can improve the experience on their end.